# Need output of a script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I run a very long bash script in Jenkins.

`./test`

At the very end of the output, I have an output like:

```
Updated to version 1.8
```

What is the best way to grab this value?

Comment: Are you using a pipeline job or a freestyle job?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Groovy Postbuild plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/). It's an old plugin, but it does the job.

You can search for strings in the console using the post stage of a the desired stage. You can use the following methods:

```
if ( manager.logContains('.*some_text.*') ) {
    echo 'some_text found!'
}

// -- or --

def consoleLine = manager.getLogMatcher('.*some_text.*').group(0)
```